# I have issue with my css

Tags: html, css, width, margin, responsive

I have currently 4 widgets witch have their own sizes. I have placed them within a main div called #box I get them centered by reducing the width to about 60% and having margin left and right on auto. If I zoom out in my browser the widget blocks moves more to the left and does not stay centered.

```html
<div id="Box"><!--Start Div Box-->
            
            <div id="TA_certificateOfExcellence580" class="Certificate Certificate-one">
   <ul id="Lnnr78SGL0" class="TA_links 4fJwNUzU0uDT">
   <li id="phnjh3wZ" class="Yi5zwOy1yHP">
   <a target="_blank" href="https://www.tripadvisor.co.za">
            <img src="https://www.tripadvisor.co.za/img/cdsi/img2/awards/CoE2014_WidgetAsset-14348-2.png" alt="TripAdvisor" 
            class="widCOEImg" /></a>
   </li>
   </ul>
   </div>
            
            
       
      <div id="TA_certificateOfExcellence654" class="Certificate Certificate-two">
   <ul id="FVuBAHp" class="TA_links CPqPZ6">
   <li id="dYmcZAj7eGOi" class="FKHiRxci">
   <a target="_blank" href="https://www.tripadvisor.co.za">
            <img src="https://www.tripadvisor.co.za/img/cdsi/img2/awards/CoE2014_WidgetAsset-14348-2.png" alt="TripAdvisor"
             class="widCOEImg" /></a>
   </li>
   </ul>
   </div>  
            
    
      
      <div id="TA_certificateOfExcellence588" class="Certificate Certificate-three">
   <ul id="E4oUIOq5y" class="TA_links JWgIqGH4nEMg">
   <li id="R3Oc1SU8Y" class="bXEYi56LVvek">
   <a target="_blank" href="https://www.tripadvisor.co.za">
            <img src="https://www.tripadvisor.co.za/img/cdsi/img2/awards/CoE2014_WidgetAsset-14348-2.png" alt="TripAdvisor"
             class="widCOEImg" /></a>
   </li>
   </ul>
   </div>
            
    
      
      <div id="TA_certificateOfExcellence396" class="Certificate Certificate-four-last">
   <ul id="ENh9NKezEOIt" class="TA_links j9dirUfR">
   <li id="LKMj2Zk" class="Z16i8koQq">
   <a target="_blank" href="https://www.tripadvisor.co.za/Attraction_Review-g312578-d2284717-Reviews-Felleng_Day_Tours-Johannesburg_Greater_Johannesburg_Gauteng.html">
            <img src="https://www.tripadvisor.co.za/img/cdsi/img2/awards/CoE2015_WidgetAsset-14348-2.png" alt="TripAdvisor"
             class="widCOEImg" /></a>
   </li>
   </ul>
   </div>
            
    
    </div><!--End Div Box-->
```

```css
#Box
{
 background-color:#CCCCCC;
 width:60%;
 margin-left:auto;
 margin-right:auto;
 
}
```

[Image before zooming browser out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nt1Ht.jpg)

[Image after zooming out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BKtpI.jpg)

Comment: please, provide your code

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to **reproduce it in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the container of your images itself is indeed centred, but the images are aligned to the left of that container. If you gave the `#box` a different background color, you'd see that immediately.

Try giving the `#Box` element a center, and then center the inside elements as well.

Since you are using `<div>` elements, I'd go for `float: left` and giving each element a specific `width` property. I'd rather go with an `inline-block` element because it's easier to center, and because you only have images which are naturally `inline-block`, but this is not what you have implemented.

Check out this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/abvt8ekj/

And the snippet:

```css
.container {
  background-color: #ee55cc;
}

#Box{
  background-color:#CCCCCC;
 width:60%;
 margin-left:auto;
 margin-right:auto;
}
#Box:after {
  display: block;
  content: "";
  clear: both;
}
.Certificate {
  width: 25%;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.Certificate ul,
.Certificate li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div id="Box"><!--Start Div Box-->
            
            <div id="TA_certificateOfExcellence580" class="Certificate Certificate-one">
   <ul id="Lnnr78SGL0" class="TA_links 4fJwNUzU0uDT">
   <li id="phnjh3wZ" class="Yi5zwOy1yHP">
   <a target="_blank" href="https://www.tripadvisor.co.za">
            <img src="https://www.tripadvisor.co.za/img/cdsi/img2/awards/CoE2014_WidgetAsset-14348-2.png" alt="TripAdvisor" 
            class="widCOEImg" /></a>
   </li>
   </ul>
   </div>
            
            
       
      <div id="TA_certificateOfExcellence654" class="Certificate Certificate-two">
   <ul id="FVuBAHp" class="TA_links CPqPZ6">
   <li id="dYmcZAj7eGOi" class="FKHiRxci">
   <a target="_blank" href="https://www.tripadvisor.co.za">
            <img src="https://www.tripadvisor.co.za/img/cdsi/img2/awards/CoE2014_WidgetAsset-14348-2.png" alt="TripAdvisor"
             class="widCOEImg" /></a>
   </li>
   </ul>
   </div>  
            
    
      
      <div id="TA_certificateOfExcellence588" class="Certificate Certificate-three">
   <ul id="E4oUIOq5y" class="TA_links JWgIqGH4nEMg">
   <li id="R3Oc1SU8Y" class="bXEYi56LVvek">
   <a target="_blank" href="https://www.tripadvisor.co.za">
            <img src="https://www.tripadvisor.co.za/img/cdsi/img2/awards/CoE2014_WidgetAsset-14348-2.png" alt="TripAdvisor"
             class="widCOEImg" /></a>
   </li>
   </ul>
   </div>
            
    
      
      <div id="TA_certificateOfExcellence396" class="Certificate Certificate-four-last">
   <ul id="ENh9NKezEOIt" class="TA_links j9dirUfR">
   <li id="LKMj2Zk" class="Z16i8koQq">
   <a target="_blank" href="https://www.tripadvisor.co.za/Attraction_Review-g312578-d2284717-Reviews-Felleng_Day_Tours-Johannesburg_Greater_Johannesburg_Gauteng.html">
            <img src="https://www.tripadvisor.co.za/img/cdsi/img2/awards/CoE2015_WidgetAsset-14348-2.png" alt="TripAdvisor"
             class="widCOEImg" /></a>
   </li>
   </ul>
   </div>
            
    
    </div><!--End Div Box-->
    </div>
```

Comment: got it to work had a look at this also works well, love how there is more than one option to all html

Answer (score 0):

you can try doing it with flexbox like this it will always stay in the center!
and if you dont want the `list-style-type` dont forget to put `padding-left:0px;` to the ul's because by default ther is a `padding :40px;`

```css
#Box{
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
}
```

```html
<div id="Box"><!--Start Div Box-->
            
            <div id="TA_certificateOfExcellence580" class="Certificate Certificate-one">
   <ul id="Lnnr78SGL0" class="TA_links 4fJwNUzU0uDT">
   <li id="phnjh3wZ" class="Yi5zwOy1yHP">
   <a target="_blank" href="https://www.tripadvisor.co.za">
            <img src="https://www.tripadvisor.co.za/img/cdsi/img2/awards/CoE2014_WidgetAsset-14348-2.png" alt="TripAdvisor" 
            class="widCOEImg" /></a>
   </li>
   </ul>
   </div>
            
            
       
      <div id="TA_certificateOfExcellence654" class="Certificate Certificate-two">
   <ul id="FVuBAHp" class="TA_links CPqPZ6">
   <li id="dYmcZAj7eGOi" class="FKHiRxci">
   <a target="_blank" href="https://www.tripadvisor.co.za">
            <img src="https://www.tripadvisor.co.za/img/cdsi/img2/awards/CoE2014_WidgetAsset-14348-2.png" alt="TripAdvisor"
             class="widCOEImg" /></a>
   </li>
   </ul>
   </div>  
            
    
      
      <div id="TA_certificateOfExcellence588" class="Certificate Certificate-three">
   <ul id="E4oUIOq5y" class="TA_links JWgIqGH4nEMg">
   <li id="R3Oc1SU8Y" class="bXEYi56LVvek">
   <a target="_blank" href="https://www.tripadvisor.co.za">
            <img src="https://www.tripadvisor.co.za/img/cdsi/img2/awards/CoE2014_WidgetAsset-14348-2.png" alt="TripAdvisor"
             class="widCOEImg" /></a>
   </li>
   </ul>
   </div>
            
    
      
      <div id="TA_certificateOfExcellence396" class="Certificate Certificate-four-last">
   <ul id="ENh9NKezEOIt" class="TA_links j9dirUfR">
   <li id="LKMj2Zk" class="Z16i8koQq">
   <a target="_blank" href="https://www.tripadvisor.co.za/Attraction_Review-g312578-d2284717-Reviews-Felleng_Day_Tours-Johannesburg_Greater_Johannesburg_Gauteng.html">
            <img src="https://www.tripadvisor.co.za/img/cdsi/img2/awards/CoE2015_WidgetAsset-14348-2.png" alt="TripAdvisor"
             class="widCOEImg" /></a>
   </li>
   </ul>
   </div>
            
    
    </div><!--End Div Box-->
```

Comment: Thank you sooo much Dany, This worked perfectly for some reason I can still not change the padding of the ul to 0. But that does'nt brother me much works when zooming out now and stays centered.

Comment: this helped perfectly appreciate all the help XD made my day

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to specify a width to your main box, you can use the text-align property :

```
text-align:center;
```

Here's a Fiddle with a little demo : https://jsfiddle.net/valentinho14/cst30wuc/

Comment: Giving a block element `display: inline-block` feels "wrong" to me. I agree that in this case, he only have images there, so it's intuitive to use `inline-block`, but he has `<div>` and `<ul>` elements which are `block` so either he has to change the markup, or go for a "block-centering" solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try instead of using the div called #box be in the center of the page, put another div inside #box1 and align that second div in the center.

Example:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
        #box1{
        background-color:black;

        }

        #box2{
        margin:auto;
        background-color:green;
        width:50px;
        height:50px;
        display:block;
        align:center;
        }
        </style>
    </head>
        <body>

        <div id = "box1">
            <div id = "box2"></div>
        </div>

        </body>
</html>
```

That did it for me, and even if you zoom in or out the div will stay in the center. Just put the images into the second div. Take care.